# Designing A class with multiple set of method implementation [c++]

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am working on an existing project which has one class for which I need an alternate member function definition. I don't want to modify existing member functions or their signatures, just an alternate definition which has to be selected run time based on some xml file (Compile time flag not preferred).
I am new to C++, so this may be a stupid question.

Please suggest design guidelines such that I don't have to change and test existing code base, and just plug my implementation.

**Example**

```
class ABC{
public:
int operate(int, int);
}  
//Assume below method to be existing implementation
ABC::operate(int op1, int op2)
{
   return op1+ op2; //add
}

//Alternate desired implementation
ABC::operate(int op1, int op2)
{
   return op1 * op2; //multiply 
}
```

Ideally I would want above to be run time selection but can fall to compile time if thats the only way.

Comment: Have you tried something already ? A little draft and being more specific would be welcome. What do you mean exactly by select compile time xml filed ?

Comment: How do you expected to read xml file at compile time ?

Comment: This depends entirely on the build system you are using. For example, with makefiles, it would be doable. With the Visual Studio IDE, I don't see an easy way.

Comment: Since this cannot be done inside the C++ code, it must be done outside the compiler, something like a script that reads the xml before compilation, and changes the compilation, f.e by inserting a compilation macro into the VS project file. But I wonder if there are any circumstances where such a solution makes sense.

Comment: Sorry I meant XML parsing at run time not compile. But I am good with compile time flags if that's the only solution

Comment: `if` and `switch` statements are how you choose which branch of code to execute based on some run-time condition.

Comment: yes  IF, SWITCH is one option but sine there are more many methods where this needs to be done, was thinking if we have better way to do this.

Comment: This suggests the Strategy pattern, perhaps coupled with a Factory pattern.

Answer (score 1):

note this thread [Reason for C++ member function hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923890/reason-for-c-member-function-hiding) regarding name-hiding in inheritence.

When a derived class implements a **NON VIRTUAL** method with the same name as in the base class, that method in the base becomes hidden, and only the derived method can be used - through objects of static type Derived.

My suggestion for you is to implement something like

```
class ABC{
public:
    int operate(int, int);
};  
//Assume below method to be existing implementation
ABC::operate(int op1, int op2)
{
    return op1+ op2; //add
}
```

Now, for your extended functionality, derive from ABC (sidenote: inheritence or composition is another discussion, read about it on google).

```
class Derived : public ABC{
     operate(int op1, int op2){
          return op1 * op2; //multiply 
     }
}
```

Now, wherever you need your new functionality, change the static type of the calling object to `Derived`, and the derived `operate` will be called.

---

A more logical solution is possible if it is possible to change ABC's `operate`'s signature to `virtual int operate(int,int);`, then polimorphism could take place, and accessing `operate` through reference types anywhere would invoke the `operate` that belongs to the dynamic type of the calling object.

Thus, you would only have to instantiate your object to be of type `Derived` rather than `ABC`.

Note that virtual method usage is not possible if `operate` is static, and it was unclear here if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I was preparing an answer but Gulzar answered meanwhile ( end of his answer )

What you need is a base notion/mechanism in C++ called **dynamic binding** ( maybe you learned it also meanwhile as your post is 1 month old )

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstddef>

    using namespace std;


    class ABC_Base
    {
        public:
            //pure virtual member function
            //compelling effective creation of the
            //function in the daughter classes
            virtual int operate(int,int) = 0;
            //virtual xtor as base will be derived
            virtual ~ABC_Base() {}
    };

    class ABC_M1 : public ABC_Base
    {
        int operate (int a, int b ) {return a+b; }
    };

    class ABC_M2 : public ABC_Base
    {
        int operate (int a, int b ) {return a*b; }
    };

    ABC_Base * createABC(string xml_filename)
    {
        int criterion = 0;

        // nullptr need at least c++11 option
        ABC_Base * ptr = nullptr;

        //read xml file and update criterion
        //see other post to do that
        //criterion = ...

        switch(criterion)
        {
            case 0:
                ptr = new ABC_M1();
                break;
            case 1:
                ptr = new ABC_M2();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return ptr;
    }


    int main()
    {
        ABC_Base * ptr = createABC("My_Config.xml");

        if (nullptr != ptr)
        {
            cout << ptr->operate(3,4) << endl;
        }

        // If you absolutely want / have to use plain old pointers
        // do not forget to release things
        // works even if ptr is null, so unconditional delete
        delete(ptr);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You may also look at notion of vtable and vptr for how dynamic binding works internally