# Difference Between c.foo() and c.parent::foo()

Tags: c++, inheritance

It's been a while since I've used C++ inheritance, and I am wondering if someone can clarify and explain something to me:

```
class parent {
  public:
    int count;
    parent() : count(0) {}
    void increase_count() {count++;}
    void print_count() {printf("Count: %d\n", count);}
};

class child : public parent {
  private:
    int other;
  public:
    child() : other(0) {}
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

  child c;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    c.print_count();
    c.increase_count();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    c.parent::print_count();
    c.parent::increase_count();
  }
}
```

It would appear that `c.<parent_function>()` and `c.parent::<parent_function>()` are the same. Does this syntax exist only for multiple inheritance? Or is there some nuance where even without multiple inheritance the `parent::` scope specifier would be different?

**EDIT:** Apologies, but I had meant to also stipulate the child not having a method of the same name.

Comment: Try making `print_count` virtual and overloading it in `child`, then you will see the difference.

Comment: Using qualified method name in the call will suppress polymorphism if the method is virtual. But in your example it would make no difference.

Comment: I apologize, I meant to also stipulate that the child doesn't have a method of the same name, but I forgot to include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It would appear that c.() and c.parent::() are the same.

They are same only if `child` does not have a function of the same name.

> Does this syntax exist only for multiple inheritance?

No. There are times when you need to call the implementation of a function in a parent class.

> Or is there some nuance where even without multiple inheritance the parent:: scope specifier would be different?

Yes.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class parent {
   public:
      virtual void print() const
      {
         std::cout << "In parent::print()\n";
      }

};

class child : public parent {
   public:
      virtual void print() const
      {
         std::cout << "In child::print()\n";
      }
};

void print(parent& p)
{
   p.print(); // Goes to child::print() when p references a child
   p.parent::print(); // Goes to parent::print() regardless
}

int main()
{
   child c;
   print(c);  
}
```

Output

```
In child::print()
In parent::print()
```

Also, there are times when you need to invoke the parent's implementation of a `virtual` member function from the child's implementation.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class parent {
   public:
      virtual void save(std::ostream& out) const
      {
         // Save the data corresponding to this class.
      }

};

class child : public parent {
   public:
      virtual void save(std::ostream& out) const
      {
         // Save the data corresponding to parent first.
         parent::save(out);

         // Save the data corresponding to this class.
      }
};

void save(parent& p, std::ostream& out)
{
   p.save(std::cout); // Calls child::save() when p references a child,
                      // which in turn calls parent::save()
}

int main()
{
   child c;
   save(c, std::cout);
}
```

Comment: Actually virtual does not change anything in this example

Comment: @Slava, true. It would make a difference only if the functions were called through a `parent&` or `parent*`.

Comment: Right, you may add function that accepts reference to `parent` and calls `print` both ways from there to make sense of using `virtual`.

Comment: I meant to also stipulate the child doesn't have a method with the same name, but I appreciate the detailed answer.

Comment: @dbeer, I answered that at the top. If `child` does not have a function of the same name, then there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple inheritance or polymorphism to demonstrate the difference. At its simplest:

```
struct B {
    int foo() { return 0; }
};

struct D : B {
    int foo() { return 1; }
};
```

Given a `D`, `d.foo()` would be 1 and `d.B::foo()` would be 0. The syntax just exists to explicitly state which member function you want to call.

Answer (score 0):

If your derived class had an overload for a parent function, then it would "hide" the parent's function and you'll need to either use the syntax that you have mentioned, or use a 'using' statement.

You can see an example in this post:
[Reason for C++ member function hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923890/reason-for-c-member-function-hiding)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a qualified function name when there is an ambiguity or you need to call a particular function.

Here is one non-obvious example then a qualified name is required.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    operator int() const { return 10; }
    friend void output( const A & )
    {
        std::cout << "friend void output" << std::endl;
    }
};

void output( int )
{
    std::cout << "void ::output" << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    output( A() );
    ::output( A() );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
friend void output
void ::output
```

The class A has friend function `output` with a parameter of type `const A &`.. If to write as it is written in the program

```
    output( A() );
```

then the friend function will be called due to the argument dependent lookup.

However if you want to call the second function with the parameter of type `int` you have to specify a qualified name.

```
    ::output( A() );
```

Otherwise again the friend function will be called.

Though in this example there is no member functions nevertheless the friend function is defined within the scope of a class. It is invisible outside the class and can be selected only due to the argument dependent lookup when an object of the class is specified as an argument.

In fact this call

```
    output( A() );
```

can be imagined like

```
    A::output( A() );
```

opposite to the call

```
    ::output( A() );
```