# template argument deduction failed when calling base function

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming, template-argument-deduction

The following C++ code produces compilation errors.

The compiler (gcc 5.2.0) complains that at line 15 it cannot find matching function for call to 'Derived::test_func()'; yet if test_func() is moved from Base to Derived, it compiles without error.

```
class Base {
   public:
   int test_func();
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
template <typename T>
int test_func(T t); 
};

template <typename T>
int Derived::test_func(T t)  
{
 test_func(); // line 15
 return 0;
}

int Base::test_func()
{
  return 0;
}
```

If the template function calls other functions in the Base class with different names (not the same name as the template function), as the following code shows, it also compiles fine.

```
class Base {
   public:
   int test_func_diff_name();
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
template <typename T>
int test_func(T t); 
};

template <typename T>
int Derived::test_func(T t)  
{
 test_func_diff_name();
 return 0;
}

int Base::test_func_diff_name()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Why is this? What is the constraints specified in C++ in calling base functions from templates? Can someone point me to some resources?

Comment: When creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please don't include line numbers. It will make it very hard for us to copy and test the code for ourselves. If you want to mark out a specific line, add a comment in the code instead. And if asking about build errors, include the actual errors (in full, complete, and copy-pasted as text) in the question.

Comment: `Base::test_func` cannot be found by the name lookup - it's hidden by the name `test_func` declared in `Dervied`. You can qualify it at the call site, as in `Base::test_func();`. Or you can bring the name into the scope of `Derived` by adding `using Base::test_func;` somewhere in `Derived` definition. This has nothing to do with templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, functions in derived classes which don't *override* functions in base classes but which have the same name *hide* all other functions with the same name in the base class.

It is usually preferable to give different functions different names.

If you really need it, you can call the base class' function by fully qualifying the name, like `Base::test_func();`

Or explicitly introduce the base class' names into the current class with `using Base::test_func;`

Comment: Variant: Adding `using Base::test_func;` in the derived class brings back the so far hidden function(s)...

Comment: The functions must also have the same signiture, right?

Comment: @Pi No. If they don't have, they are overloads. You might want to override instead, then yes, signatures must be the same (with few exceptions). But for overriding, the base class's function must be declared virtual!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you also point me to some documents which explains the rational behind this rule?

Comment: @Aconcagua Sorry, I meant if the name is the same and the signiture different, they also do not hide the other overloads.

Comment: @yangsuli - the reason is that the standard says so, and that it's better this way :) This was [already asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923890/reason-for-c-member-function-hiding), with no definitive answer...

Comment: @Pi They *do* - if you do not want to, you need the using clause mentioned in my very first comment: `class C { public: void f() { } }; class D : public C { using C::f; void f(int) { f(); } };` - compile, then try compiling with the using commented out.

Comment: @Aconcagua Great. Thanks.