# C++: What does "hide" means in overwrite method

Tags: c++, overwrite

Code

```cpp
class A
{
    public:
        A(){};
        ~A(){};
        void Init()
        {
            cout << "A::Init()" << endl;
        };
    private:
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        B(){};
        ~B(){};
        void Init()
        {
            cout << "B::Init()" << endl;
            A::Init();
        };
    private:
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A* pa = &b;

    b.Init();
    cout << "------------" << endl;
    pa->Init();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
B::Init()
A::Init()
------------
A::Init()
```

> overwrite: subclass method hides base class method...

That's what I saw from a post on the internet. I understand it as, for class B, it has no idea what `A::Init()` is, why it still can call `A::Init()`? What's wrong part of my understanding?

Comment: In addition to what's in the duplicate, If you have a modern compiler declaring `B`'s `Init` should be `void Init() override` so you can get a more meaningful error message if it does not override.

Comment: See [Reason for C++ member function hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11923890/3422102) and the link it is a dupe of.

Comment: The problem is not calling `A::Init()`, but calling `Init()` without the `A::` qualification. You've demonstrated a symptom of the problem since one should expect that `b.Init()` and `pa->Init()` call the same function. (And the rest is probably covered by the duplicate.)