# Overriding functions in abstract base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I have a base class that contains two functions of the same name, one with a `vector<int>` as a parameter and one with an `int`. The idea is that child classes will define their own methods to process an int and the base class will be able to deal with either option. But it doesn't compile at the moment.

```
class base {
public:
  virtual void toBeCalled(int i) const = 0;

  virtual void toBeCalled(std::vector<int> iVec) const
  {
    std::cout << "base::toBeCalled(vec<int>)" << std::endl;
  }
};  

class derived : public base {
public:
  virtual void toBeCalled(int i) const
  {
    std::cout << "derived::toBeCalled(int)" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  derived d;
  std::vector<int> iVec;

  int i = 0;

  d.toBeCalled (i);
  d.toBeCalled (iVec);  //<< Compile error: Cannot convert from std::vector<int> to int

  return 0;
}
```

I can get it to work by using a base class object in main() `base *d = new derived()` but I'd prefer not to do this if possible, as I'd like to access some of the derived classes functions.

Comment: use using of base names in derived class. Or use another name for the conflicting funtions.

Comment: @WhozCraig  I hope it was a typo during copy/paste to SO :-).

Comment: You're right, it is actually there and I've corrected the question now. Same error persists though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `using base::toBeCalled;` in `class derived`.

I'm pretty sure this is a dupe, but I can't find one, so I won't go into detail. But when you override (or overload) a function in a derived class you hide all base class versions of that function.

Rationale for the behavior is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12036004/13005

Comment: +1 great link. =P (note: add it to the `public:` section of the derived class, btw).

Answer (score 3):

You have not caused `class derived` to be derived from base.

```
class derived: public base {
```

Comment: This happens, when you expcect things to be working properly...

Comment: You're right, it should have been there and is in my code, but still I get the same error. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that you forgot to specify the base class when copying your code here. This is, instead of:

```
class derived {
public: // and so on
```

you have:

```
class derived : public base {
public: // and so on
```

When you define methods for a class, these methods hide any methods with the same name in the base class. In this case, when you override method `toBeCalled()`, you are saying that class `derived` will only have those signatures you are specifying; any other signature in the base class will be hidden:

```
class derived : public base {
public:
  virtual void toBeCalled(int i) const
  {
    std::cout << "derived::toBeCalled(int)" << std::endl;
  }
  // void base::toBeCalled(std::vector<int> iVec) const is hidden and
  // cannot be accessed through this class
};
```

Since you don't want to override the second version of the method in your derived classes, your best way out is to explicitly tell the compiler that you want to import (as opposed to hide) all base class versions of the method into your derived class. This is done via a `using` clause:

```
class derived : public base {
public:
  using base::toBeCalled; // Any version of method toBeCalled() not overriden here
                          // will now be taken from the base class
  virtual void toBeCalled(int i) const
  {
    std::cout << "derived::toBeCalled(int)" << std::endl;
  }
  // void base::toBeCalled(std::vector<int> iVec) const is taken
  // from the base class now
};
```

Comment: +1 but it might be worth pointing out that name hiding is not restricted to member functions: the derived class could have a private char called `toBeCalled` and this would still hide all of the base class' `toBeCalled`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Absolutely right, but I did not want to overcomplicate my answer. This mechanism is not method hiding but name hiding.

Answer (score 0):

you can call it by something like this,

```
  base.toBeCalled(iVec);  // here base is not base class name...it is reference to Parent Class
```

other way --

```
class derived : base  {  // inherit base class
public:
  virtual void toBeCalled(int i) const
  {
    std::cout << "derived::toBeCalled(int)" << std::endl;
  }
};
```