# The std::stringstream class and rdbuf() member function

Tags: c++

The `basic_iostream` class template includes two overloads for `rdbuf()` - one is a `const` member function which returns a pointer to the internal streambuf in use, the other takes a single `streambuf*` argument, and *sets* the internal pointer.

However, `std::stringstream` overloads the `rdbuf()` function as follows:

```
  stringbuf_type* rdbuf() const;
```

Since only the "getter" version is overloaded, the "setter" version which takes an `streambuf*` argument is hidden (due to [member function hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928535/name-hiding-and-fragile-base-problem)), and thus inaccessible via a `stringstream` instance.

Is there some reason this was done?  Is it possible to change the internal `streambuf` object used by a stringstream?  It seems this might be desirable in some situations, say - for example, you want to use a stringstream object that converts all input to lowercase.  A custom stringbuf class deriving from `std::stringbuf` would be ideal in that case.  However, without the `rdbuf(streambuf*)` function, there's no way to change the internal streambuf object used by `stringstream`.

So, why doesn't `std::stringstream` provide a way to *set* the internal stringbuf object used?

***note***: to avoid confusion, I'm *not* talking about setting the internal *memory buffer* of a stringstream, rather I'm talking specifically about *setting* the internal `std::basic_stringbuf` object used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some reason this was done?

Since accessing the `streambuf` is more common than changing it, that case was made more convenient.

The special functions added by `stringstream` won't work unless the buffer is a `streambuf`, so it doesn't really make sense to treat it as a `stringstream` with a different buffer. You can use the entire base `iostream` class interface, though.

> Is it possible to change the internal `streambuf` object used by a stringstream?

Sure, just qualify the member access: `s.iostream::rdbuf( newbuf )`. You should similarly qualify any subsequent call to the `rdbuf()` accessor if the buffer isn't a `std::stringbuf`, to avoid an illegal cast to that class.

Or, just create an `iostream &` reference and forget the original `stringstream`, except for the purpose of destroying it.

Comment: You say "since accessing the `streambuf` is more common than changing it, that case was made more convenient."  But... why doesn't `std::stringstream` just have a second override: `stringbuf* stringstream::rdbuf(stringbuf* sb);` ?

Comment: @Siler `filebuf` has equivalent overloads, so I guess they don't really expect you to be swapping buffers at all through buffer-owning interfaces. It's a bit hackish to be honest. Usually it's appropriate to create a new base class object.