# How to make base class template function visible for derived class instances without casting or duplicating signature?

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any way to avoid cast when calling a base class template function from a derived class instance? Suppose the following:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void quux() = 0;
    template <class T> void quux() { ... }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    void quux() override {}
};
```

Then later on usage of class `Bar`:

```
Bar bar;
bar.quux<int>();                    // error: type 'int' unexpected
static_cast<Foo&>(bar).quux<int>(); // OK
```

Any way to make this less obnoxious and make function `quux` callable on instances of `Bar` without having to duplicate the function signatures directly in `Bar` implementation? I'm aware of dependent name lookup, looking for a maintainable way to solve this for all derived classes.

Comment: What compiler and standard are you using? Seems to work fine for me: https://godbolt.org/z/KdzK5eGnc

Comment: Indeed, I might have removed too much code. I updated the question, and the live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/fE5WKK3h1

Comment: I just realize now that my issue is not a visibility issue, but rather a disambiguation issue; the compiler taking the non-template version.

Comment: *"I just realize now that my issue is not a visibility issue"* -- it's usually called "hiding", so I'd call it a visibility issue, not a disambiguation one. See, for example, [name hiding and fragile base problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928535/) -- as soon as you declared `Bar::quux()`, almost everything named `quux` in the base class became hidden -- the exception is the function that was overridden instead of hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add [`using Foo::quux;`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#In_class_definition):

```cpp
class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    using Foo::quux;
    void quux() override {}
};
```

Comment: This works! But for others reading this, the `using` declaration **must** be before the function override, otherwise the compiler might still pick the wrong one.